# How can I run a powershell script from startup/autostart folder with bat file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Are those files put into a cmd context and then just executed/typed ?
A .bat file is just run, but a powershell file can`t just be run.

How can I make it run without bat file?

Comment: I [still say](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35776256/1683264) you should use a [batch + PowerShell chimera](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=45095#p45095).  That saves you from having to deal with execution policies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a batch file (`.bat` or `.cmd` file). Just create a shortcut to `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File whatever.ps1`. You may need to use the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter to allow scripts. Run `powershell /?` from a Cmd.exe or PowerShell prompt for more information.

Comment: But how do I know when I log into a server where the script is autostarted that IT IS indeed autostarted showing a date + time? Therefore I would like to have a bat calling the .ps1. But with the .bat are other probs waiting...

Comment: What do you mean by 'IT IS indeed autostarted showing a date + time'? Are you talking about running something from the `Startup` folder, or...? (I think you need to clarify your question.)

Comment: yes I want to run the .ps1 from startup folder. I want all the output of the .ps1 like Write-Host in the cmd window. So I can control what my script when something.

Comment: Just run powershell.exe and specify the `-File` parameter to run a script. The PowerShell script will run in a console window.

Comment: ok then I really got something wrong in my head. I will try and let you know!

Comment: I did: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file C:\Running_FileWatcher\filewatcher.ps1 -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted then the window shuts down and my filewatcher does not work. Should the window not stay open?

Comment: @Elisabeth Try adding -WindowStyle Maximized as well if your relying on the script output to be shown to the user.

Comment: Make sure that the `-File` parameter is last on the powershell.exe command line. (The /? help, `powershell /?`, tells us this explicitly.)